# Como transformar str em int?

Tags: python, conversão-de-tipo

Tentei transformar o placar em `int` como eu fazia no JavaScript mas não funcionou:

```
placar = "0 x 0"
print(int(placar))
```

Eu esperava que mostrasse 0 mas resultou em um erro, como eu faço para transformar o placar em `int`?

Comment: Qual é o resultado que você espera obter?

Comment: eu esperava obter o primeiro 0

Comment: Não seria melhor separar o valor em duas variáveis, como `pontuacaoUm = 0` e `pontuacaoDois = 0`?

Comment: se for 0 x 1 seria 0

Comment: placar ou multiplicação isso?

Comment: placar mesmo, pegaria o primeiro numero

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O que está fazendo não faz sentido, pois a *string* `0 x 0` não é um formato numérico válido, por isso resulta no erro.

Para obter os dois valores que formam o placar, você pode utilizar o método `split` da *string*:

```
placar = '0 x 2'
a, b = map(int, placar.split(' x '))
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/IgPQPU) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/N7D8/0)</sup>

Assim, `a` valerá 0, primeiro valor do placar, e `b` valerá 2, segundo valor do placar, ambos do tipo `int`.

Agora, se o formato desta *string* poder variar, por exemplo, `0x0`, sem espaços, `0  x  0`, com mais de um espaço, etc, talvez seja mais viável você analisar através de uma expressão regular:

```
import re

placar = "0x0"

groups = re.match("(\d+)\s*x\s*(\d+)", placar)

if groups:
    a, b = int(groups[1]), int(groups[2])
    print(a, b)
```

Comment: muito massa esse jeito utilizando esse `re`

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer que mostra 0 na resposta, dá pra fazer desse jeito:

```
placar = "0 x 0"

print(int(placar[0]))
```

Output: `0`

Se você quer guardar cada valor em uma variável:

```
valor = int(placar[0])
valor2 = int(placar[4])
```

Obs: Desse modo só funciona quando o placar estiver no formato `AxB`, em que A e B sejam de 0 a 9.

Se o valor de um dos resultados for maior que 9, você pode fazer desta maneira trabalhando de forma estática:

```
placar = "0 x 21"

valor = int(placar[0])
valor2 = int(placar[4:6])

print(valor)
print(valor2)
```

Output:

```
0
21
```